# Stream Huge Lists with FreeMarker , out of memory exception

Tags: java, out-of-memory, freemarker

**Description**

There is a big database of players `200.000` and below is the `.ftl model`:

```
<header> ... <header>
<main>
!Here is the problem
<#list items as vo>
  <name> $vo.name} </name>
  <surname> ${vo.surname} </surname>
  <abilities> ${vo.abilities} </abilites>
</#list>
</main>
<footer>  ... </footer>
```

---

**So what's wrong ?**

The above works good when i have a small amount of players , let's say `5.000`.

**What i am trying to do ?**

I need to create this document at once for all the players which means i have to pass a list with `100.000` or more players . This is going to cause `Java OutOfMemoryException`.

So i am fetching every time `1.000` players and creating the list , but the problem is .... how to pass all the players as before ? I have one `.ftl` model and FreeMarker doesn't support something like that ...

I want all the `200.000`  players at the same document .

What technique i should use :) ?

The Java class looks like this :

```
public FinalXMLVo extends HashMap<String,Object>{

 ...
 private List<Player> players;

 public FinalXMLVo(....,List<Player> players){

  ...
  this.put("items",players);

 }

...

}
```

Comment: How much memory do you need? Have you tried increasing the java heap?

Comment: Sometimes it maybe need like 5 GB . It collects 1 million or more lottery players at the end of month . I found a solution creating 3 separate `ftl files` , one header , one foot and one file that is appended to the header . So i create 100 players then append to the header file then again and again until all players.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `Writer` you pass to FreeMarker buffer all the output? Maybe seeing where the `OutOfMemoryException` usually occurs helps to figure that out.

Other than that, I'm not aware of any reason why a longer list would consume more memory in FreeMarker. At least in such a basic use case you are showing, it should be able to keep render even an infinite list.

Also, if instead of a `List` you are using an `Iterator`, that also frees up memory as far as the source of the data (like a `ResultSet` maybe) is smart enough to not buffer all of it.

Comment: I have just added the Java class model so you can see where the problem is . I am passing all the players at once .

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS That's outside FreeMarker though. Is creating the `List` itself fails, or it's the template that fails later? Anyway, in either case, what I said in my answer holds, so try to look into those.